# Multiline comments in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I would like to know how to use multiline comments in a kivy (.kv) file.
I tried the following codes and neither of them worked but the one line comment '#' works well.

```
"""
I am
a multiline
comment.
"""

'''
Me
too...
'''
```

Comment: Put a # on every line. I don't think there is another multiline comment syntax, or the ability (in general) to use multiline strings as you are doing there.

Comment: Strings are not comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kivy doesn't support multiline comments and it seems they aren't gonna add it any time soon.

You can check a PR about this [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4650).